# jQuery Change All <element> HTML IF that HTML = Something

Tags: jquery, html

So essentially I have a ton of paragraph tags that contain non-breaking spaces.  While I know, removing them and correcting the issue is the real concern - I'm working on a bandaid fix to auto-remove them after the page loads via jQuery.

Essentially I have:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Several hundred times in a page.

I want to remove them all via jQuery but of course not remove all the other paragraphs on the page which don't solely contain non-breaking spaces.

This should be fairly simple but for some reason I'm not getting it; something like:

```
if($.trim($('p').html()) == '&nbsp;'){
$(this).remove();
}
```

That is only hitting the first paragraph on the page, I need to hit all of them.

Comment: Thus far; none of the 4 proposed solution work fully.  More details soon -- although, the problem is accurate.

Comment: With respect, at least two of them work fully for *the question as posted*. One even has demos proving it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Figured it out; the lack of a $.trim() was the problem in your suggested solution (just noticed you had a sub-note about it).  Some of the p tags are spaced/tabbed/new line broken before the close tag.

Comment: *"just noticed you had a sub-note about it"* Sorry, I added that later when I saw you had one in your question (I'd missed that originally). Not a *lot* later, but later, you'd probably seen the earlier version.

Comment: No problem - thanks a ton for the help!  Now I can finally be done for the day ;)  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery can help you with that:

```
$("p").html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    if (oldHtml === "&nbsp;") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyule)

That uses [the variant of the jQuery `html` function that accepts a function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). Add a `$.trim` if required.

Alternately:

```
$("p").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.html() === "&nbsp;") {
      $this.remove();
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyule/2)

That uses [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and then [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1) to retrieve the HTML of each element. Again, add a `$.trim` if required.

Comment: Finally solution contained the second suggestion from T.J. with a trim:

$("p").each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
if ($.trim($this.html()) === "&nbsp;") {
    $this.remove();
}
});

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's each() function to iterate over every one of them:

```
$('p').each(function()
{
    if ($.trim($(this).html()) == '&nbsp;')
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
```

You can also use the ":contains" selector to only get the paragraphs that contain a non-breaking space:

```
$('p:contains("&nbsp;")')
```

Comment: *"You can also use the ":contains" selector to only get the paragraphs that contain a non-breaking space"* You could, but then you'd remove *any* paragraph containing a non-breaking space *anywhere*. The OP's intent is clearly to remove the ones that contain *only* a non-breaking space.

Comment: You'd remove any paragraph containing a non-breaking space anywhere _if_ you didn't check for it inside the each() function.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is correct. But as soon as you call `html()` (or `attr()` or `text()` or anything like that) it just calls it for the first element matched. So you have to iterate all the elements and test/remove each one of them

```
$(p).each(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).html()) == '&nbsp;') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: *"But as soon as you call html()...it just calls it for the first element matched."* Not so, if you pass in a function.

Answer (score 0):

If they're all like that I would use regex.